# How to Remove XmlElement ? (XmlNode vs XmlElement)

Tags: c#, xml, c#-2.0, xmlnode

I try to remove some XmlElements from my Xml file in C#2.0.
I can remove it successfully with `XmlNode.Remove()` method. But there is no `Remove` method in `XmlElement`.

I googled and found this.

*elements are a type of node. In fact, if you look at the members of XmlNode and XmlElement in the .NET Framework, you will see that they are very much alike, but XmlElement has more going on. It inherits XmlNode and then is further customized. This is because an element is more specialized. A node is more general in scope. The document is a node, a processing instruction is a node, and so forth. Elements are different. If you look at the XmlNodeType property of an element, you will see that it is Element, one of the many types of nodes you find.*

If element are a type of node, then why I can't use remove command. Then how?

```
XmlDocument doc_AlarmSettingUp = new XmlDocument();
doc_AlarmSettingUp.Load(xmlFile_AlarmSettingUp);
XmlNode rootDest = doc_AlarmSettingUp.SelectSingleNode("/Equipment/AlarmSettingUp/EnabledALIDs");
foreach (XmlElement el_AlarmSettingUp in doc_AlarmSettingUp.SelectNodes("/Equipment/AlarmSettingUp/EnabledALIDs/ALID"))
{
    XmlElement outEl;
    if (lookup.TryGetValue(el_AlarmSettingUp.GetAttribute("alid"), out outEl))
    {
        // exists; element now in "other"
        // Console.WriteLine("exists");
    }
    else
    {
        // doesn't exist
        Console.WriteLine("doesn't exist");
        // Then How can I remove element with an element method? Thanks.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code should work on any `XmlElement`:

```
if (outEl.ParentNode != null) outEl.ParentNode.RemoveChild(outEl);
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do with the code above? It doesn't relate to the question as far as I can see.

What is the problem with calling Remove on an XmlElement (which is an XmlNode)?

Comment: I try to find a way to remove `XmlElement`. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, [`XmlNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode_members%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) doesn't have a `Remove()` method either. It does have a `RemoveChild(XmlNode)` method, and so does [`XmlElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement_members%28v=VS.80%29.aspx). You should use `RemoveChild` of the parent element to remove the child element.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I should write the whole statement as `XmlNode.RemoveChile(XmlNode)`;